# What should the new default off-topic close reason be?

Tags: discussion, meta, close-reasons

The default Meta Stack Overflow close reason currently reads:

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the
> software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), within the scope
> defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Which doesn't seem completely appropriate anymore considering "software that powers the Stack Exchange" would be a question asked on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com). I would suggest just trimming it down to:

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow within the scope
> defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Does anyone have any suggestions/better ideas?

Comment: I wonder if we need to add more emphasis (somewhere) that this site is now _only_ about SO, not the entire network. We could add a sentence at the end pointing to the new MSE.

Comment: Actually, the current close reason matches other site metas, so it is probably intended to be as-is.

Comment: One problem with the current close reason is that it links to [the SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/), which only has a [single page about meta.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) that's not even directly linked from the front page. At least, it would be better to link directly to the ["What is 'meta'?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is actually the default for all child metas and that's on purpose. While it is true that there is a network-wide meta, each community can (and to a large extent should) handle most issues internally. That's how our system scales - by enabling individual communities to take care of themselves. We (both developers and community managers) check for bugs, requests, posts, etc. on all sites across the network, and a new user on Stack Overflow doesn't need to know or care about the wider network until and unless they decide to check it out for themselves.

Stack Overflow has never had to learn this because it shared a meta with everyone else, but there isn't much reason for it to be any different going forward. Your own meta should be your first line of support, discussion, bug reports, and even feature requests. Discuss them all within your own community and, if there is ever a need, come to Meta Stack Exchange to bring them forth to other sites.

Answer (score 20):

On SO we have the following for "off topic because it should be on SF".

> Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

So what about something similar?

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow within the scope defined in the help center. For questions about the Stack Exchange network, see [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

A wordsmith can fix my English.

To reply to ughoavgfhw, while this is different from other meta sites, MSO itself has a different history. I think we need to put more emphasis on "we are not the meta for everything" now.

Comment: I'm sure there will be tons of questions on MSO that should now go to MSE. The `Belongs to MSE` option is a must.

Comment: I'm rather against sticking a link in a close reason that's not appropriate to all questions that can be closed for that reason, as some people may just be like "Oooo, a link, let's ask my question there too" (not really reading / understanding what the reason actually says) (which is especially likely, considering that they managed to ask the way-off-topic question here already). I think we should considering making MSE a migration target instead, or adding a separate reason for that.

Comment: @Dukeling, what about the "don't migrate crap" rule. I agree that a migration path would be much better, but what about the lower-quality questions? Close them with the standard close reason and call it a day?

Comment: @gunr2171 If that will be a problem, we could just "add a separate [non-migration] reason for that" instead then (although, we do have 4 migration paths on [so], and that doesn't seem to be a problem, otherwise I assume they would've removed that), or, as Anna mentioned, just leave them here.