# Someone continuously down-voting my questions

Tags: support, downvotes

On March 13 I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037426/how-to-change-activity-after-5-seconds/29037646#29037646) on a question and [@2dee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178337/2dee)
commented on my answer and was asking for proof of what I have said in my answer, but at that moment I couldn't find the proof so I told them that I would send a link as I find the proof.

[image: his comment]

On next day they again asked me for the proof of my answer and since I couldn't show them the proof, they started writing some rude comments on my answer and also down-voted my answer.

I flagged their comments as **rude or offensive**, and moderator **Brad Larson** reviewed the comments and deleted it and also warned both of us not to do such again.

But they didn't stop there; they started down-voting the questions I have asked.

On March 15, they down-voted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797850/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-days).

On March 16, they down-voted these two questions:

[image]

On March 18, they down-voted these two questions

[image]

On March 19, they down-voted this question,

[image]

And on March 20, they have down-voted these two questions **twice!!**

[image]

Ever since I flagged their comments on my answer, they started down-voting my questions.

And they are not new to SO, so they are aware of [Serial up voting or serial down voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and that's why they down-vote one or two of my questions every day.

Maybe they have another SO account also, through which they have down-voted my two same questions twice today (both down-voted questions are the same and were also down-voted at the same time).

My questions are old (more than a month at least), so there is no possibility that they could be visible in newest questions queue.

There's no way I can get rid of them or flag anything or can call to Moderators about this. And instead of bothering with them and ruining the site I asked the question here (I hope I get some help here).

And if moderators don't take any action against them, I am sure they will down-vote more questions tomorrow.

**Is there any way to stop them down-voting my questions?**

Comment: yeah you can flag. Flag one of the downvoted answers, use a custom flag, and explain briefly. Now that you have a meta question.... that's done :P

Comment: So how did one user downvote *The program 'keytool'...* and *What is cloud data center?* questions twice, again? (hint: you can't with one account).

Comment: Devil's advocate, is "revenge downvoting" still a problem if the posts actually warrant downvotes?  I'm not saying that they do, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: ... and I wouldn't be so sure that those posts are not downvote worthy...

Comment: [Pinging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250041#comment167583_250041) [moderators](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251212#comment167584_251213) [directly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266077#comment167586_266077) [through](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272612#comment167589_272612) [comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272348#comment167590_272348) instead of using the appropriate channel (i.e. flags) is a sure-fire way to *not* get this to stop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no no, see I have said in my question, he may have another SO account and from both accounts he has down voted my questions. My all questions are old (more that month at least) so there is no possibility that they could be visible in newest questions queue.

Comment: Be aware that the ["Meta Effect"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect), plus the generally low quality of the questions in, erm, question, may mean complaining about a relatively small number of down-votes was counter-productive...

Comment: How can you be so sure all of these downvotes are coming from this one person?

Comment: I ended up voting to close some of these.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I get down votes on my questions, it's fine, I'll understand they are bad. But I am getting down votes only since last few days! and if nobody stops him, he definitely will down vote my questions tomorrow too.

Comment: @KevinB they are, because today as I got down votes I checked his profile and his last seen was just a minute before. He is targeting me since last few days.

Comment: ah! dont let votes bother u

Comment: @Coffee what would you do if somebody continuously down votes your posts?

Comment: Drink lots of coffee I presume.

Comment: Have you considered that this is merely the community downvoting what they observe to be content not showing research effort or a clear problem statement?

Comment: @Apurva i would laugh and just move on with my day if i found someone was downvoting me in this way, but, then again, downvotes to me don't really bother me due to the rep that I have allocated.

Comment: @KevinB - True, with 60K a few downvotes dont mean anytthing. What is troubling though is when we feel it is malicious, that someone is "out to hurt us"  ... this is always unnerving. I wish we can fix it, but it's not easy .  I won't lie, there were times when I felt that downvotes were "extra"

Comment: @Coffee I did ignore him for 2-3 days but he's not stopping

Comment: @Apurva - Reflect on this - that person has so much time they get some evil pleasure from downvoting someone they don't know. Honest? I'd laugh it off. Some people in the world are truly miserable I guess, to go targeting others through useless internet points

Comment: @Apurva Also consider that they are losing at least half the rep they are making you lose by downvoting your answers.

Comment: @KevinB he's not losing any rap because he down votes only my questions not answers.

Comment: You marked this answer as one of the offending ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037426/how-to-change-activity-after-5-seconds/29037646#29037646

Comment: @KevinB he started commenting on my answer you posted a link of. And what happened afterwards, you can see my question here.

Comment: There is no evidence to link the member you are accusing and the downvotes

Comment: That was a good question. Why so many downvotes on his question??? The world is full of #@$&%§! It makes me delete my account.

Answer (score 17):

Look, two things:

- *RELAX*. It doesn't matter. If receiving a few downvotes is affecting you this much then you may benefit from some quiet meditation in the shower (well, that's where I like to reflect, at least) on why votes on this site are such an important part of your self-image. This will help you not just here, but in many areas of your life. Chill out, get a good night's sleep, and move on. Receiving downvotes on an SE site doesn't make you a bad person. It really doesn't. Even if one or two people specifically have it out for you, it's their problem, not yours.
- If you suspect suspicious activity, use the proper tools. Flags (a *single* flag with an explanation and polite request for an investigation is enough), contact support (once) if necessary, and *be patient and reasonable*. Posting an ["answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288451/616460) to this question in all bold pleading for more help is *not* one of the proper tools (and really, think about where this anxiety is coming from...). If one user is serially downvoting you the system does have ways to detect that and if it is truly happening it *will* be dealt with eventually. *It's not going to kill you if it takes a few days to resolve.* And even if it isn't dealt with, just have a little self-confidence and move on.

Your user profile [currently reads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3900120/apurva) "This day will never come again, do what make you feel proud tomorrow." So, handle this in a way that will make you feel proud tomorrow.